Working with storage when inheriting from another smart contract
I've written two contracts: A and B, where contract B inherits contract A.
Why the value of y is 0 in contract B?
contract A {
    uint immutable x;

    constructor() {
        x = 42;
    }

    function f() internal  pure returns(uint256) {
        return x;
    }
}
   
contract B is A {
    uint public y = f();
}


y value is returning 41 though. Can you please confirm ?

Because the value of x will be 42 only after we deploy contract A. But what's happening in this case is we are deploying them separately, which means contract B is not waiting for contract A to execute the constructor logic. It simply calls the f() function and f() function returning the default value of x which is zero.
In other words contract B is inheriting contract A, which means it is inheriting the state before the deployment of A. If you set the x variable directly like this:
uint256 immutable x = 42;
Then contract B will inherit this value, and y will return 42.
